# button in my html look strange

Tags: html, button, tags

[image]

Why does the button name appear left from it ?

Comment: Umm... what? I don't understand.

Comment: You should post your code here, not the screenshot

Comment: Define the text on the button using `value="Text"`, not by putting something between opening and closing tags.

Comment: I like how the screenshot has the word midterm everywhere. It's raising a big ethical and moral flag for me. I assume this is all legal and good @Jongz?

Comment: No it isn't a exam @Sanchit.

it's my practice file so don'y worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<input type="button" value="Query"  onclick="query()"/>
```

in place of  tag because Different browsers use different default types for the  element.

If you use the  element in an HTML form, different browsers may submit different values. Use  to create buttons in an HTML form.